# How Toggle AutoHide MenuBar Setting?

Tags: swift, objective-c, dock

Dock And MenuBar Preferences below:

[image: Dock Menu Bar Preferences]

MenuBar True/False AutoHide Button below:

[image]

In Dock And Menu Bar Preferences, exists a True/False AutoHide Menu Bar Button.

How can I get this value? and how can I change this value programmatically?

Comment: See what you can do with Apple Script for it.

Comment: I believe that with Applescript is possible, but is needed to open the window of Preferences and simulate a click at button. I am searching something with behavior similar a this CoreDock Private Apis -> https://gist.github.com/w0lfschild/90db263867f469738c01e9e2d937f874, an function that set directly the bool value of this option